# angular function using then in promise with return statement

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, return

I need to return an empty string twice in my function (see return ''. When I use catch error, it is working, but I cannot figure out how to edit the function so the catch error is removed.
this is my function:

```
agencies$: Observable<Agency[]> = this.afs.collection<Agency[]>('agencies')
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(tap(console.log),
      mergeMap((agencies: Agency[]) => from(agencies)),
      mergeMap((agency: Agency) => {
        return forkJoin([
          this.afStorage.storage
            .refFromURL('gs://agency-logos-paid-keeper')
            .child(`/thumbnails/${agency.agencyId}_700x100.png`)
            .getDownloadURL().then(url => url).catch(error => {
            return '';
          }),
          this.afStorage.storage
            .refFromURL('gs://benefit-cards-paid-keeper').child(`/${agency.agencyId}_200x200.png`)
            .getDownloadURL().then(url => url).catch(error => {
            return '';
          })])
          .pipe(
            tap(([logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl]) => console.log('a', logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl)),
            map(([logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl]) => ({
                ...agency, logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl
              })
            ), catchError((error) => {
              return of({...agency});
            }));
      }),
      map((agency: Agency) => [agency]),
      scan((agencies: Agency[], agency: Agency[]) => {

        const agencyExists = agencies.find(a => a.agencyId === agency[0].agencyId);
        if (!agencyExists) {
          return [...agencies, ...agency];
        }
        return agencies;
      }));
```

I just want to remove the .catch(error) after then (both of them). but when I try it, I'm getting an error. How do I remove the catch error, while still having a return statement. I know it's an elementary question, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: If you do not `catchError` then an error will be thrown if the observable returns an error, that is the expected behavior unless I am missing something

Comment: It might be I who's missing something... But with the catch error, everything is displaying correctly. If I start to play with the then function, I don't get my url the way I need it

Answer (score 0):

From experience mixing promises and Observables usually causes problems. In you code I have changed the promises to Observables and everything seems to work

```typescript
  agencies$: Observable<any> = this.afs
    .collection<Agency[]>("agencies")
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      mergeMap((agencies: Agency[]) => from(agencies)),
      mergeMap((agency: Agency) => {
        return forkJoin([
          from(
            this.afStorage.storage
              .refFromURL("gs://agency-logos-paid-keeper")
              .child(`/thumbnails/${agency.agencyId}_700x100.png`)
              .getDownloadURL()
          ),
          from(
            this.afStorage.storage
              .refFromURL("gs://benefit-cards-paid-keeper")
              .child(`/${agency.agencyId}_200x200.png`)
              .getDownloadURL()
          )
        ]).pipe(
          tap(([logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl]) =>
            console.log("a", logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl)
          ),
          map(([logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl]) => ({
            ...agency,
            logoUrl,
            benefitCardPhotoUrl
          }))
          // catchError(error => {
          //   return of({ ...agency });
          // })
        );
      }),
      map((agency: Agency) => [agency]),
      scan((agencies: Agency[], agency: Agency[]) => {
        const agencyExists = agencies.find(
          a => a.agencyId === agency[0].agencyId
        );
        if (!agencyExists) {
          return [...agencies, ...agency];
        }
        return agencies;
      })
    );
```

[image]

See this [demo illustration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nsckpc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: the problem is that some of the agencies don't have images. My code (with the catch error) does display the images, though it gives me a get error. Your code also gives me a get error, but it will only display those agencies that have images, and there's an additional error that the image doesn't exist in firebase storage(see image attached at end of the question).